# Failed to load bundle - Could not connect to development server

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

I've been looking for a solution to this issue for a day now but couldn't fix it.

I have not used react native for a month when everything was working fine.

Now, if I try to run an existing project that used to work (react native 0.59.5) or a brand new project (react native 0.59.9) with the iOS simulator on my mac, I get the error:

> Failed to load bundle - Could not connect to development server

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the issue. Was thinking it might be watchman related issue and wanted to use the command `brew reinstall watchman`to reinstall it. By running this command, I found an error

> Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Mojave. Install the Command Line Tools: xcode-select --install

Looks like the command line tools for xCode was not available anymore.
I launched the command `xcode-select --install` and then reinstalled watchman just in case. It is now working!

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't connect to development server error

This error is received when the metro bundler isn't running in port 8081. To start the bundler, from project folder run:

```
npm start
```

Now, try reloading your app (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for iOS / <kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for Android).

Also, check your terminal in case the project failed initial build due to some error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that. The metro bundler seems running on port 8081 and the project build is successful. Also tried react-native start. But no success.